# Change output style (grouping) of Mysql SQL command

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How to create filter view on this sql command ?

```
select t1.ean, t2.date, t2.hour,
   (t1.consumption *
    (case when type = 'B' then type_b_coefficient
          when type = 'A' and region = 'EAST' then type_a_east_coefficient
          when type = 'A' and region = 'WEST' then type_a_west_coefficient
          else 1
     end) *
    (case when category = 11 then cat_11_coefficient
          when category = 21 then cat_21_coefficient
          else 1
     end)
   ) as net_consumption
from table1 t1 join
 table2 t2
 on t2.date = t1.from_date
```

Now query showing EAN / Hour / day /Consumption. And I need for show
EAN/DAY
DAY
and DAY and hour.

If I change GROUP by query gets wrong math result. In this command all math works good

Filter meaning:

Now Query show output like this:

```
  ean      day      hour         net_consumption
  1234  2020-01-01   1              1.12312312
  1234  2020-01-01   2              0.23038382
  2838  2020-01-01   1              2.3043043
```

And how to do for this views -

```
 ean      day           net_consumption
1234  2020-01-01          10.12312312
5678  2020-01-01           8.12312312
2838  2020-01-01           5.22392229
```

or -

```
     day           net_consumption
   2020-01-01          120.12312312
   2020-01-02           68.12312312
   2020-01-03           30.22392229
```

If I do it with GROUP BY i get wrong math result (etc wrong counted consumption like much lower if I count it manualy. First query works)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Aggregates may come out bigger than expected when involved in a `JOIN`.

Here's what happens.

1. The tables are joined to [logically] create a temp table with the suitable combinations of rows.
2. The aggregates are computed based on this [probably larger] temp table.
3. Then the `GROUP BY` shrinks the number of rows back down.

Usually, the cure for inflated numbers (and for poor performance) is to *first* do the aggregation and GROUPing with as few columns and as few tables as possible.  Then do

```
 SELECT ...
     FROM ( that query to get aggregates ) AS x
     JOIN table(s) ON ...  -- to get other columns
```

Answer (score -1):

you should try something like below

```
Select 
    ean,
    date,
    Sum(net_consumption) as net_consumption
from
(
    select 
        t1.ean, 
        t2.date, 
        t2.hour,
       t1.consumption *
        case when type = 'B' then type_b_coefficient
              when type = 'A' and region = 'EAST' then type_a_east_coefficient
              when type = 'A' and region = 'WEST' then type_a_west_coefficient
              else 1
         end *
        case when category = 11 then cat_11_coefficient
              when category = 21 then cat_21_coefficient
              else 1
         end
        as net_consumption
    from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.date = t1.from_date

)T
group by ean, date
```

or

```
Select 
    date,
    Sum(net_consumption) as net_consumption
from
(
    select 
        t1.ean, 
        t2.date, 
        t2.hour,
       t1.consumption *
        case when type = 'B' then type_b_coefficient
              when type = 'A' and region = 'EAST' then type_a_east_coefficient
              when type = 'A' and region = 'WEST' then type_a_west_coefficient
              else 1
         end *
        case when category = 11 then cat_11_coefficient
              when category = 21 then cat_21_coefficient
              else 1
         end
        as net_consumption
    from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.date = t1.from_date

)T
group by date
```